# Cant access Magento 2.4.0 backend Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document

Tags: magento2

I'm testing Upgrade to Magento 2.4  but getting the error below. I've read that this error can relate to a missing title attribute in a custom extension. To try and isolate teh issue I have remove all the extensions from /app/code/ folder and then ran upgrade , compile process again  but the issue still remains even with all extensions removed.

Any idea how to debug?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 13


Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 13

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php:229]
#2 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php:165]
#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#4 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#5 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#6 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php:26]
#7 Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:205]
#8 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:157]
#9 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:125]
#10 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#11 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#13 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [sitemaps/speedcrete/htdocs/index.php:44]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your store operates with MSI disabled - the new modules you will also need to disable are prefixed with 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickup'

Disabling all of the Magento_InventoryInStorePickup modules fixed (could not create an acl object) in admin error for me.

Thanks user552769 for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

.. finally resolved. in 2.3.x I had disabled the inventory MSI modules but 2.4.0 add's some new modules. These need to be disabled as well. Then the acl error is resolved.

Comment: What modules exactly? I have the habbit of disabling everything not needed, but im not sure what the msi modules are? thx